# How to retrieve URL fragment identifier in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, fragment-identifier, jspx

Is there an easy way to get the URL fragment identifier (everything after the hash '#') in JSP?  I've tried just finding even the URL itself which includes the fragment identifier with `${pageContext.request.queryString}` and other similar `pageContext.request` methods without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized fragment identifiers are never sent to the server!  That's why I can't seem to find them in JSP methods...